# Unable to Upload Application to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, testflight, braintree

I currently haven iOS app that I'm looking to upload to TestFlight. I believe I have all the necessary information, but when I try to archive the project, it says a specific file BraintreeCore.h cannot be found. I am using Braintree in this project and ran a pod install so the entire Braintree folder is in the Pods section of my project. Do I have to do something with this folder in order to make it so the project can be archived. Does anyone have any similar experiences to this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you remove Braintree from your podfile and run pod install, does it still fail?

Comment: was able to fix this issue by changing header search path